# How to Subtract two values from last column and bring to next in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, rolling-computation

I have this table

How can I roll over this Quantity based on previous row's calculations? Please help me out here.

+Adding:

I am sorry for not being clear. So I have few products which has date, Inventory and Projection. I want to group by for each group and create another column that has last row's inventory - Projection in the next row. Right now Inventory is same for all rows for each group. Inventory should be subtracting based on projection in every row and add Upcoming Qty.

[Sample File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOred.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly the structure of the data is and how you would like to adjust it?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I have edited my question. Thanks for your time

Comment: @HabibKhan Please let me know if you know any a way to copy from that image and recreate the same data

Comment: @akrun is it okay if I email you the details along with data? I am a newbie here in Stack Overflow so not sure how to do that. Or you can email me at hu.khan4@gmail.com and I will send you the dataset along with how I want it